# AS3 Camera showing nothing

Tags: camera, actionscript-3

This time i'm getting a strange error while triying to take a picture from my web cam.

With the object **flash.media.Camera** I can access to the webcam and show a live stream (using **flash.media.Video** and attaching the camera).

The issue comes when I try to take the picture, after a few success (The number varies), the video stream goes grey and I can't take pics anymore.

The code is very simple.

In an init function I set the camera like this

```
        _camera = Camera.getCamera();
        if(! _camera ){
            lostSignal();
            _output.addChild(myLayer);
            return;
        }


        if(type == WebcamType.ONLY_PHOTO || type == WebcamType.COMPLETE_WEBCAM){
            _camera.setMode(OUTPUT_WIDTH_HD,OUTPUT_HEIGHT_HD, 30);
        } else {
            _camera.setMode(OUTPUT_WIDTH,OUTPUT_HEIGHT, 30);
        }
        _camera.setQuality(0, 100);

        _video.attachCamera(_camera);
```

Finally y get an image of what is showing on the screen.

```
private function endCountdown(evt:Event):void {

        if (type == WebcamType.COMPLETE_WEBCAM || type == WebcamType.ONLY_PHOTO) {
            fotoBitmapData = new BitmapData ( OUTPUT_WIDTH_HD, OUTPUT_HEIGHT_HD );
            fotoBitmapData.draw(_outputHD)
        }
        fotoBitmap = new Bitmap(fotoBitmapData)
        addChild(fotoBitmap);
        addChild(_btnTipiace);
        fotoBitmap.width = _video.width;
        fotoBitmap.height = _video.height;
        fotoBitmap.x = _video.x+_output.x;
        fotoBitmap.y = _video.y+_output.y;

    }
```

Debuggig I found something strange in te Camera object.

```
"this._camera"  flash.media.Camera (@1c1ab731)  
activityLevel   -1 [0xffffffff]
bandwidth   0   
currentFPS  0
fps 30 [0x1e]   
height  720 [0x2d0] 
index   0   
keyFrameInterval    15 [0xf]    
loopback    false   
motionLevel 0   
motionTimeout   200000000 [0xbebc200]   
muted   false   
name    "Microsoft® LifeCam Cinema(TM)" 
position    "unknown"   
quality 100 [0x64]  
width   1280 [0x500]
```

Both **activityLevel    -1** and **currentFPS   0** had abnormal values.

It's simple but when I take a few pics the video goes grey. Any idea why?

Thanks.

Comment: How many is _"when I take a few pics"_? Looks like you're holding 2 megs of bitmap data per pic... Could be memory issue making video/sound not available for preview. Use either `Capabilities` API or `System` API (one of those is correct) to check memory availability...

Comment: I just fix my issue, it was because Skype was taking away the control of the cam.